# Spurious characters in Lua string

Tags: luatex, memoir, unicode

I'm trying to generate a section title programatically from some constituent strings.  The simplified MWE just concatenates them (the live system will do more complex processing) but I get a leading zero and intermediate characters ˙" (x3F 22).  Input file is UTF8 encoded but the MWE strings should only be ASCII.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, onecolumn, dvipsnames, final]{memoir}%

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}%


\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 

\directlua{dofile("TexMacros.lua")}

\newcommand{\Bsection[3]}{\directlua{Bsection(#1,#2,#3)}} % This defines the tex macro

\begin{document} 

\chapter{Chapter the first}

\Bsection{"Section pre-text"}{"T"}{"Section post-text"}

\section{\Bsection{"String pre-text"}{"T"}{"String post-text"}}

\end{document}
```

The relevant function in the TexMacros.lua file is :

```
function Bsection(s, sb, sc)
    local t=""
    t = t..s..sb..sc
    t = string.gsub(t, "[\192-\255][\128-\191]*", "")
    tex.sprint(t)
    return t
end
```

Output:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter the first
0Section pre-textT"Section post-text"
1.10String pre-textT"String post-text"
```

Comment: never use `[utf8]{inputenc}` with luatex, you also should not need `luatexbase` other than for compatibility with very early lualatex realeases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the syntax for `\newcommand` wrong, you want

```
\newcommand{\Bsection}[3]{\directlua{Bsection(#1,#2,#3)}} % This defines the tex macro
```

not

```
\newcommand{\Bsection[3]}{\directlua{Bsection(#1,#2,#3)}} % This defines the tex macro
```

Comment: By the way, that wrong `\newcommand` is processed as if it were `\newcommand\Bsection[3][0]{\directlua{#1,#2,#3}}`, so that's where the `0` is coming from.

Comment: Obvious when it's pointed out :-) Much appreciated David.